# MDADM two disks of different ages from same array

Tags: raid-1, mdadm

I have an mdadm mirror.  One of the drives was failing, and through not concentrating, the a new drive was mirrored against the failing drive, which had been out of the array for a while, so is a mirror of a month old version.

The system is now back booting against the up to date disk, and I want to add the new disk to this array.  But it thinks that it is already part of the array, only an older version.

So I were to boot up my system with both the new version of the disk, and the old version, which will mdadm decide is "correct"?  It is mirror, so both are consistent with themselves.

My main concern is that if I boot them both, the older version is going to overwrite the current version - this doesn't seem likely, but I don't know how mdadm makes decisions in this case.  Ultimately, I'll blank the older version to avoid the possibility of something going wrong.  But I'd still like to know.

Answer (score 1):

Linux MD tracks a variety of information about each disk.  One of these items is "event count", a measure of how "recent" the information on the disk is.  With a RAID-1 array, if two drives have different event counts, MD will select the one with the higher count as "current", and copy from it to bring the other drive up to date.

You can check the event count of a disk through `mdadm`:

```
$ mdadm --examine /dev/sde 
/dev/sde:

...         

Events : 16219323
```

Comment: Great, so I could have just checked the event counters on both disks, added it to the array without wiping if it was less.